# Identify an unknown app

Tags: applications

I really need your help, big time. I searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer to this. Can anyone tell me what app is this? I took a screenshot of the device but it's locked, cannot open Notification Bar.

It's the one that looks like a little Devil face.
What is this app/notification from? I'd really appreciate if anyone knows please share the answer with me.

[image: The Devil icon what is it?]

Comment: If you can't unlock the device, how would you verify solutions?

Comment: If someone is able to just tell me what this Devil icon App is, it's solved for me. I don't wanna unlock it, I wanna know what is that App name/called/link

Comment: It might, **might** be devil's attorney. However, you should really unlock it and check. Its easy, and there is no reason not to-unless you stole it.

Answer (score 1):

That app is the [**Opera VPN**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.vpn) app, telling you that you're connected to their VPN service.

Here it is on my phone (third notification icon):

[image]

And the matching app (third notification):

[image]

For the record, that's a Viking's helmet, not a devil face.

For more on what VPNs are, see [Android Authority's relevant article](http://www.androidauthority.com/vpn-and-app-list-for-beginner-users-192672/).

Answer (score 0):

Open `Settings`->`Apps`->`Running`. One of those running apps will be the devil face.